# is CKeditor contextmenu platform dependent?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor 4, I used following code to remove **`contextmenu`** for spellcheck.

```
config.removePlugins = 'language,tableresize,liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
```

for

```
spellcheck='true'
```

But is it platform independent. Currently I am working on Windows. Is it work on iOS and others as there should be some dictionary used by **spellcheck**!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-3.6.2-Released/) any version above 3.6.1 should work on IOS.

Also read the [faq](http://ckeditor.com/support/faq/features#question7) particularly number 7

Comment: but my problem is not with CKeditor. I have edited my question. sorry for inconvenience!